# How to avoid publishing references to already bundled npm dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, rollup, npm-publish

When building an npm package, sometimes it will use local packages that won't be published separately to a public repo. These are already bundled with the main package code. But the published package.json still has references to the dependency.

```
package.json
"dependencies":{"localPackage"}
```

The rollup node resolve plugin will bundle code from the dependencies but the result of npm publish still has the dependencies listed. When the module is used, it tries to install those dependencies but they aren't found because "localPackage" wasn't published.

Is there a way to remove dependency references from the package.json that have been bundled?

I've seen custom modules to modify the package.json file before using npm publish:

https://github.com/sstur/lean-package

Is there a standard way to do this using npm or is it expected that even bundled dependencies are published?

Answer (score 1):

Using devDependencies works ok for bundling the code and the dependency not being required on install.

The references are still in the output so that would probably need a custom process to modify the package.json before publishing.

It would be useful if npm publish had a way to delete references to specified modules.